# \t not producing in the statement print("Jawahar\tNavodaya")? Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

When using `print("Jawahar\tNavodaya")` the tab space is not generating in output

Tried `\t` in print() for other strings generating fine output. Ex: `print("Navodaya\tVidyalaya")` is generating tab space.  But `print("wahar\tNavodaya")` is generating less than tab space and more than single space

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> print(".\t,")
.   ,
>>> print("...\t,")
... ,
```

Tabs align output to predetermined columns. They are *not* replacements for, say, 4 spaces.